# lettre images in vec implement in singlepart

Tags: rust

Hello i am using Rust with crate lettre 0.10.0-rc-4.

I found an answer on Github, but could not really implement it.
I want to loop over a vec of images and add it to lettre email body sender.
Here is the Code with the Vec:

```
  fn add_attachment(image_body: Vec<calc_price::products::Products>) -> Vec<lettre::message::SinglePart> {
    let mut res: Vec<lettre::message::MultiPart>;
    image_body.iter().enumerate().map( |(i, product)| {
    //   product.crop.leftDistanceToCutLine.iter().enumerate().map( |(ind, left)| {
      let content_id = String::from("") + &0.to_string() + &"-" + &0.to_string() + &"-" + &image_body[0].picture.name;
      let filebody = fs::read("src/images/".to_string() + &image_body[0].picture.name+ &"." + &"jpeg").unwrap();
      let content_type = "image/jpeg".parse().unwrap(); 
      Attachment::new_inline(content_id).body(filebody, content_type) // return attachment
      //   })
    })
    .collect::<Vec<lettre::message::SinglePart>>()
  }
```

But the singlepart of lettre does not accept Vec.
Is there a workaround to it?

```
.singlepart(                  
  add_attachment(email_order.body.products.clone())
  )
```

With error expected struct `lettre::message::SinglePart`, found struct `std::vec::Vec`

The answer i found is on: [github](https://github.com/lettre/lettre/issues/611#issuecomment-902391719)

Comment: You should call `singlepart` multiple times. Once for each item in your `Vec`.

Comment: can you provide some code, so that i can close this and be sure it is working.
I am new to Rust and found it confusing! Thanks

Comment: Note: I do not know how many images there will be!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by looping over the vec and returning the multipart

```
            .multipart(
                  add_attachment(email_order.body.products.clone()) // vec with attachment body
                  .iter().fold(MultiPart::related().singlepart(
                    SinglePart::builder()
                      .header(header::ContentType::TEXT_HTML)
                      .body(order_email_content)
                  ), |acc: lettre::message::MultiPart, el: &lettre::message::SinglePart| {
                    acc.singlepart(el.clone())})
                ))
```